# Regex for extracting sql statement in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have written following regex for extracting sql statement from string

```
((?:SELECT|INSERT)[\s\S]*?\;)
```

It's working fine but it's capturing last quotes and semicolon while I want string between quotes?
Any help will be appreciated

[image: Output Snapshot]

Comment: Is that suppose to be C# code you're running the regex on?  If so it seems to be missing plus signs for concatenating those strings together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookahead to avoid that.

```
((?:SELECT|INSERT)[\s\S]*?)(?=";)
```

Using this positive lookahead `(?=";)` it makes sure that your regex ends before that `";`, and it will not capture in your group.

Answer (score 0):

Regexp:

```
(?:SELECT|INSERT)[\s\S]*?(?=\"|\;)
```

Input:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT "
"SELECT DISTINCT "
"SELECT DISTINCT "
"SELECT DISTINCT ";
```

Output: (Example...)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
SELECT DISTINCT
SELECT DISTINCT
SELECT DISTINCT
```

C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?:SELECT|INSERT)[\s\S]*?(?=\""|\;)";
        string input = @"""SELECT DISTINCT ""
""SELECT DISTINCT ""
""SELECT DISTINCT ""
""SELECT DISTINCT "";";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/rzBTpo/2